# index problem in list comprehension if requirement

Tags: python, list, indexing

I am trying to get values' indexes those are bigger than threshold. However, some frames does not have any value bigger than 0.5. In this case, I am getting error. How can I fix this index problem if the conditions are not met.

```
print(pred_score)

>>> [0.9752067, 0.13946067, 0.12231697, 0.10389509, 0.09314783, 0.08375313, 0.07981376, 0.06718858, 0.064989634, 0.05775991]
```

After thresholding

```
pred_t = [pred_score.index(x) for x in pred_score if x > self.threshold][-1] # Get list of index with score greater than threshold.
```

Ordinary results is:

```
print(pred_t)

>>>0
```

However for this case;

```
[0.29323328, 0.20563416, 0.19228794, 0.12607153, 0.112677306, 0.10169901, 0.090266354, 0.06262935, 0.062495198, 0.060448203, 0.058922235]
```

I got this error due to if condition:

```
pred_t = [pred_score.index(x) for x in pred_score if x > self.threshold][-1] 
# Get list of index with score greater than threshold.
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: That's because `[pred_score.index(x) for x in pred_score if x > self.threshold]` is giving you an empty list

Answer (score 3):

You need to check if the list is empty before indexing.
you can do something like this.

```
pred_score_threshold = [pred_score.index(x) for x in pred_score if x > self.threshold]
if pred_score_threshold:
    return pred_score_threshold[-1]
```

of if you are using python 3.8

```
if res := [pred_score.index(x) for x in pred_score if x > self.threshold]:
    return res[-1]
```